# SurfaceViewRender not rendering captured Frames

Tags: android, webrtc, surfaceview

I am trying to build a WebRTC application in Android Studio, but I am failing to understand why the SurfaceViewRender is not displaying the captured frames (even though in the Android Logs I see that the frames are captured by the VideoCapturer)

I tried many ways to make the SurfaceViewRender to display the frames.

Here is the latest configuration:
Android Manifest:

```
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />
    <queries android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="true"/>
```

Init of the surfaceViewRenderer

```
        val surfaceViewRenderer = findViewById<SurfaceViewRenderer>(R.id.surfaceViewRenderer)
        surfaceViewRenderer.init(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext,null)
        surfaceViewRenderer.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT)
        surfaceViewRenderer.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)
        surfaceViewRenderer.setEnableHardwareScaler(true)
        surfaceViewRenderer.setMirror(true)
        surfaceViewRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.toArgb())
        surfaceViewRenderer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

The addFrametoLocalVideoView (which is SurfaceVideoView called from another class):

```
    private void addFramesToLocalVideoView() {
        if(localVideoView!=null && localVideoView.isAttachedToWindow()){

            var widthPixels = (int)(120 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            var heightPixels = (int)(160 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            localVideoView.post(()->videoCapturer.startCapture(widthPixels, heightPixels, 24));
            videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer.isScreencast());
            localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("localVideoTrack", videoSource);
            localVideoTrack.addSink(localVideoView);
            peerConnection.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
            Log.d(TAG, "initializePeerConnections:"  + localVideoView.isEnabled());
        }
    }
```

The VideoCapturer Methods:

```
    public VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer() {

        // Get the list of available cameras using Camera2Enumerator
        Camera2Enumerator enumerator = new Camera2Enumerator(context);
        String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();

        // Select the front or back camera (or any specific camera)
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                // Use the front-facing camera
                return createCameraCapturer(enumerator, deviceName);
            }
        }

        return null; // Handle case where no suitable camera is found
    }
    private VideoCapturer createCameraCapturer(CameraEnumerator enumerator, String deviceName) {
        SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CameraTexture", null);
        VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, new CustomVideoCapturer("VideoCapturer"));
        videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, context,new CustomCapturerObserver("CapturerObserver"));

        return videoCapturer;
    }
```

Some logs:

```
Camera2Session: Opening camera 1
onCameraOpening: 1
startInputReason = 1
Camera2Session: Camera opened.
Camera2Session: Camera capture session configured.
Camera2Session: Using video stabilization.
Camera2Session: Using continuous video auto-focus.
Camera2Session: Camera device successfully started.
CameraCapturer: Create session done. Switch state: IDLE
onCapturerStarted: true
onFirstFrameAvailable
onFrameCaptured: org.webrtc.VideoFrame@23da5de
onFrameCaptured: org.webrtc.VideoFrame@47d73bf
```